# Обработка вебхука с битрикс24 на Python Flask

Tags: python, битрикс, flask, webhook

вообще не понимаю в чём проблема.
Надо обрабатывать вебхук с Битрикс 24. Но получаю ошибку HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST.
Может кто поможет, а то дедлайн горит)
Вот код:

```
import requests
import json
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
         r = request.get_json()
         print(r)

return '<h1>hello world</h1>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Вот ошибка которую выдаёт:

> "¦¢¥£)>K¾+6Þ¿6Ø{vÓÄ0HAb» <À,À" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, как я понял Битрикс отправляет вебхуки по 80 порту, так что следует просто сменить порт на 80. Но так же после этого следует настроить ngix, дабы избежать неприятностей) 
Так же помог этот код:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def result():
     print(request.form)
     return 'OK'
```

Answer (score 1):

для исходящего веб-хука с событием *создание задачи* я использовал:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def result():
    print(request.form)
    return 'OK'
```

Comment: Не, не помогло, может я что то не так в битриксе указываю?
Адресс: https://11.11.11.111:8000/(1 для примера)

Comment: а в веб-хуке б24 внешний IP который перенаправляет запросы на  11.11.11.111:8000?

Comment: Да, это vps сервер, ну запросы то он принимает, только криво как то.